# What are patch operator and what is the meaning of patching

Tags: rxjs

I am learning the concept of pipe() (Rxjs) from [document link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)

In document mentioned in the above link  patch operator , prototype patching are mentioned which I am not getting, what are they.

Please anyone can help me understand what is patching, patch operator, prototype patching.

Comment: The document explains it. Previously, RxJS used an Observable class with very few methods, and importing the operators consisted in "patching" the Observable class, i.e. adding methods to the Observable class dynamically.

Comment: @JB Nizet, patching means adding methods to the Observable class dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment: *the operators consisted in "patching" the Observable class, i.e. adding methods to the Observable class dynamically*.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks for the immediate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patching is extending existing functionality of Objects. It is not RxJS specific, but general JavaScript thing. It is also called Monkey Patching. I suggest you have a look at [Basics of Monkey Patching](https://davidwalsh.name/monkey-patching).